# using getchar to receive input from file and insert into char pointer giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, getchar

There is a file called prog1.txt that is being read into my program. To execute, I use the name of the file and a '<' symbol to read in the file. (./a.out < prog1.txt). When i read it in however, i immediately receive a segmentation fault. Here is what I have written that is giving this issue:

```
    char *strPtr;
    while(((*strPtr = getchar()) != EOF) && (*strPtr != '\n')) {
        strPtr++;
    }
```

I have researched other questions, but I can't find a problem whose solution is usable for this. What is causing the segmentation fault??

Comment: You're not allocating memory for your pointer, is pointing to garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer `char* strPtr`, but it might not point to anything that you can use. You'll need to allocate some memory. `char* strPtr = malloc(numChars);` You should also free it after you're finished with the allocated memory: `free(strPtr);`

You'll need to set a maximum number of characters you can read in. In this case I use numChars.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a pointer does not create something for it to point at.   When using a pointer (or array syntax) it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure things are set up correctly.

`getchar()` returns `int`, and `EOF` is a value that cannot be represented using a `char`.   Comparing any value of type `char` with `EOF` will therefore always fail.

You need to deal with both these concerns.  You are not.

For example;

```
char *strPtr = malloc(10);
int length = 0;
if (strPtr != NULL)
{
     int achar; 

     while(length < 10 && (achar = getchar()) != EOF && achar != '\n')
     {
         strPtr[length] = (char)achar;
         ++length;
     }
}

 /* do whatever is needed with strPtr and length*/

free(strPtr);
```

The check that `strPtr` is not `NULL` is to ensure the `malloc()` call succeeded before trying to write to the allocated array.

`length` is being used to ensure the code does not write to `strPtr` past the allocated length.

`achar` is used to check for `EOF` before converting the value to a `char` (not after, as in your code).

Answer (score 0):

Use an array

```
char strPtr[10];
int temp;
int i = 0;
while( i < 10 && ((temp = getchar()) != EOF) && (temp != '\n')) {
    strPtr[i] = temp;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `!= EOF` not be able to correctly compare to char type.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I did not know that, other than changing the array to be an `int` array, what would fix this code?

Comment: E.g `int ch;while( i < 10 && ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) && ch != '\n') {
    strPtr[i++]=ch;
}` also There might be necessary to reserve for `'\0'`. E.g `char strPtr[10+1]={0};`